# cpu bound task switches threads while executing NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

my question concerns cpu bound, synchronous tasks in node without using worker threads. I have this basic HTTP server:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

function heavy() {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 20_000_000_000; i++) {
    counter++;
  }
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/block") {
    heavy();
  }
  if (req.url === "/file") {
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
    fs.readFile("1GB.bin", (err, data) => {});
  }
  res.end("Hello World " + Date.now());
});

server.listen(3000);
```

when I navigate to /block in the browser, I inspected what was actually happening to my computer threads, and here is what I got
[image]

cpu2 and cpu6 threads were switching between each other symmetrically. I tried this experiment several times and each time I got the same results. My question is why is this happening? Isn't Node supposed to use just 1 thread all the time? Maybe I'm misinterpreting the word "thread" and actually when people are talking about node threads they mean cores? I would really appreciate clarification of these questions.

My os is ubuntu 22.04 with 4 cores and 8 threads.

Comment: Looking at your CPU usage chart, ist __is__ using only one thread for your busy loop.

Comment: that's the confusing part. what I refer to as a thread is blue and orange lines and both of those threads are managed by a single core. So, what do you mean by one thread?

Comment: Those lines are core usage percentages, not threads. A thread can switch cores and usually does unless pinned to a specific core.

Comment: but my laptop only contains 4 cores and there are 8 lines in total, that's why I assumed those lines represented threads, but now I get you. By thread, I meant a processor thread which is 8 in my case but you definitely mean something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.  First, nodejs is not bound to a specific CPU core.  The OS is free to share CPU cores with other things executing on your system or time slice the nodejs execution out for a moment and then start it up again on a different CPU core so your nodejs execution may not always stay on the same CPU core.

Second, nodejs uses an internal thread pool for asynchronous file I/O.  So, when you call `fs.readfile()`, that will ultimately get turned into an `fs.open()`, and `fs.read()` and an `fs.close()` each of which has a native code implementation that uses the nodejs internal thread pool.  That uses OS threads that are different than the single thread that executes your Javascript.  By default, the nodejs thread pool contains four threads.  If you attempt more than four asynchronous file I/O operations at once, the first four will each get one of the threads from the pool and the others will be queued until a thread becomes available.

> Isn't Node supposed to use just 1 thread all the time?

That is ONLY for executing your actual Javascript code, not necessarily for library functions that have native code implementations.  So, your Javascript itself executes only in a single thread, but once you call a library function that has a native code implementation, all bets are off and other threads may be used in that native code implementation.

Comment: I experimented a little and tried to read 5 times asynchronously, the first 4 files took about 1200ms to read and I expected the fifth one would take about 2400ms since the thread pool can only use 4 threads at once by default but the fifth one also finished reading in 1200ms. what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @bearthum - As I say in my answer, `fs.readFile()` consists of multiple separate operations which will all get interleaved.  So, it's not like it reads the first four files in their entirety before it starts on the 5th file.  Instead, 5 `fs.open()` calls will happen.  The first four will start immediately.  The fifth will be queued.  But that fifth `fs.open()` will get to go as soon as one of the first four `fs.open()` calls finishes before any of the `fs.read()` calls.  If `fs.readFile()` was implemented with only one native call, then you would probably see what you were expecting.

Comment: thanks for the clarification,  but is there a function with one native call(except for the ones mentioned above) so that I could see the result I'm expecting?

Comment: @bearthum - File operations are a little tricky for pure parallelizism because they ultimately all go through the same disk controller.  Perhaps doing a large `fs.write()` on five separate already open file handles to an SSD (not a spinning hard drive).  Or, even better one of the asynchronous crypto operations like a long sequence of `crypto.randomBytes()` that also use the thread pool?